# Magnolia CMS with Spring MVC Template module creation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, magnolia

I created the Magnolia + Spring MVC + maven projects followed the [manual](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom). I added `MainTemplate.java`, `TextComponent.java`, `contentArea.jsp` and `mainTemplate.ftl` to the `acme-module` skeleton project. Projects archive downloadable [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwlk512lts1pyfw/acme.zip?dl=0). When I runned the jetty container with `mvn jetty:run-war` in the web project, I noticed on the console:
`2016-05-26 11:19:18,850 INFO  .magnolia.module.blossom.template.TemplateExporter: Registered templates [myModule:components/text,myModule:components/main]`

But in the admin UI there is no any available templates in the combo, when I want to create a new Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `myModule:components/main` in MainTemplate to `myModule:pages/main`.

That's how Magnolia knows if a template is a page or a component. Right now you have two component templates and no page template.

Comment: Thanks @sigget. The "Main" is appeared in the combo. Now I will fix the Spring java config in the acme-module project, because the maven archetype generated wrong thinks: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "/blossomSampleModule/pages/mainTemplate.ftl" not found. So in the FreemarkerRenderingConfiguration and JspRenderingConfiguration should be the prefix "/acmeModule/" and not "/blossomSampleModule/".

Comment: Fixed project is available in the upper link.